# Как передать по http одним POST запросом файл (двоичные данные) и JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, formdata

```
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blob);
        formData.append('text', ['dima', 'sasha']);
```

Файл передается и принимается на сервере нормально, а массив нет.
Когда смотрю запрос в DevTools вижу это:

```
  Form Data:
file: (binary)
text: (unable to decode value)
```

Вот запрос:

```
fetch('/api/newPost', {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед передачей преобразуйте массив в json-строку. Передавать форму надо как `multipart/form-data`, а потом на сервере обрабатывать каждое поле отдельно.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob);
formData.append('text', JSON.stringify(['dima', 'sasha']));

fetch('/api/newPost', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: formData
})
```